# My ListView is null and i don't get why

Tags: android, listview, null

iv been trying to populate my listView onto an activity but my listView keeps remains null even after initializing it. I checked the error log and ran it through the debugger and I concluded that I'm not initializing it properly , though im not sure where.

**MainActivity**

```
  public class DisplayCountryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_country);

        // Construct the data source
        ArrayList<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views

        //context=this;
         listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Contract.Country.contentUri, null, null, null, null);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            countries.add(new Country(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("country")),cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("capital")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("area")),cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("population")),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("official_lang"))));
        }


            CountryAdaptor adapter = new CountryAdaptor(this, countries);

            // Attach the adapter to a ListView
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

**Adapter**

```
    public class CountryAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public CountryAdaptor(Context context, ArrayList<Country> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Country country = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_item, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView countryTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dp_country);
        TextView capitalTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dp_capital);
        TextView areaTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dp_area);
        TextView populationTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dp_population);
        TextView officialLanguageTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dp_official_language);

        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        countryTv.setText(country.getCountry());
        capitalTv.setText(country.getCapital());
        areaTv.setText(country.numberToString(country.getArea()));
        populationTv.setText(country.numberToString(country.getArea()));
        officialLanguageTv.setText(country.getOfficial_lang());

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**List View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DisplayCountryActivity">


    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/list_view">
    </ListView>
```

Comment: "listView keeps returning nulls" this is ambiguous. Please explain more what you mean by "nulls". Btw it's not my downvote.

Comment: without the layouts, anything can be null.

Comment: "enter code here" it's not very informative. Try to update your question, please.

Comment: my apologies , its updated , i hope that's clear enough  Mariano Zorrilla

Comment: You are using a null inflater, change it to these convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.country_item, parent, false);

Comment: i just tried that (using getContext()) and it doesnt work , my listview is still null @Stankovitch

Comment: What do you mean by *"My ListView is null"* ? You have a NullPointerException or your `ListView` is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i solved the problem . first of all , just to clear the air up , the list view variable was null when i tried to initialize it with my xml file . my mistake was that i had the listview xml file as a stand alone file , there was no formatting to it. so basically my mistake was not placing the ListView tags inside the content xml file that i was using . All i had to do was add the ListView tag to my content xml file